# How does touch tmp/restart.txt actually work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I see people here saying to touch tmp/restart.txt to restart a rails sever, but I am interested to know how this actually works. restart.txt is an empty file in the tmp folder, so how does Rails know to restart the server when you touch the file? I.e. where is the code that allows this feature to work, since it's not in restart.txt?

Comment: The code is in the server of course. Details depend on the server you're using. But features like this usually work by polling: `stat`ing the file once a second or so. If the file exists and its last-modified time is later than the server start time, it restarts. Alternately, OSes have ways of registering callbacks to receive file system change notifications, but there's no OS-independent standard afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `config/spring.rb` you'll see that [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is configured to watch this file. I believe the default is to poll every 2 seconds.

```rb
Spring.watch(
  "tmp/restart.txt",
  "tmp/caching-dev.txt"
)
```